# Adding a Sliding Menu to a Tab Layout

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, slidingmenu

This is my first time I implement a Sliding Menu in Android. I downloaded a sample code which works perfectly. Then I tried to merge it with a Tab layout but the app keeps force closing when I press the tab which contains the Sliding Menu. Each code works alone perfectly.TabLayout Code:

```
 public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity { 
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
  @Override   
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
   setContentView(R.layout.tab_main);         
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();            
     // Tab for Photos     
   TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");   
     // setting Title and Icon for the Tab     
   photospec.setIndicator("Photos");   
     Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);    
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);            
     // Tab for Songs      
  TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");      
         songspec
.setIndicator("Songs");    
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);  
      songspec.setContent(songsIntent);       
          // Tab for Videos   
     TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos");
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
    }
}
```

Main Activity Code which contains the Sling Menu:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
02-07 16:03:09.734: D/AbsListView(29642): Get MotionRecognitionManager
02-07 16:03:09.734: D/AndroidRuntime(29642): Shutting down VM
02-07 16:03:09.734: W/dalvikvm(29642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4137e2a0)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1941)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:705)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:369)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:560)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:128)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
02-07 16:03:09.739: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    ... 19 more
02-07 16:03:11.244: I/Process(29642): Sending signal. PID: 29642 SIG: 9
```

So when I go the photos or videos tab it works perfectly, but when I access the photos tab the app force closes :/
So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's on your line 86 in the MainActivity ?

Comment: getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); @Andros

Comment: What is your min API level ? 11 ?

Comment: yeah I changed that now to 14 and still didn't work

Comment: What is the style applied to your MainActivity ? Please ensure that your theme contain an ActionBar. Also, check this useful link : http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html

Comment: when I added the tablayout to the sliding menu code, I didn't change anything with the MainActivty. I just don't get it why when I call the intent from the tab it fc.